# How to setup HAProxy to add access token to client requests

Tags: docker, haproxy

I have a client that can only make requests without authentication information.

I would like to use HAProxy or a similar proxy solution to add OAuth authentication to these client requests.

I already succeeded to add a Bearer token to the client requests. See below for the haproxy.cfg with some placeholders.

```
frontend front
  mode http
  bind *:8080
  default_backend   servers
  http-request add-header Authorization "Bearer {{ .Env.ACCESS_TOKEN}}"

backend servers
  mode http
  server server1 myserver.com:443 ssl
```

The problem is that the access tokens have a TTL of 24 hours. So I need to refresh them or get a new token periodically.

Does HAProxy support this already?

I can write some script to get a new access token periodically, update the config and restart HAProxy. Is this a good approach when running HAProxy in docker? Are there better solutions?

Comment: It is not clear if the client is the application that will access the resource server (in OAuth term) or it something else. If Yes that what is exactly the role of myserver.com here and if No then maybe you need to explain better the requirements.
It would be easier to answer you if you explain who are the "Resource Owner, client, authorization server, etc" and where HAProxy or any other proxy sits in all of this.

Comment: Could you clarify - what HAProxy is expected to support? Pulling a new env value updated outside or obtaining a new token?

Comment: Ideally of course obtaining the token but I think this is not possible. So it would be good enough to be able to update the token externally and make HAProxy use it without restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to create/test your script using [`Lua`](https://www.lua.org/), it is now supported in the latest versions, check [How Lua runs in HAProxy](https://www.arpalert.org/src/haproxy-lua-api/1.9/index.html).

An example of this but using [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) + `Lua`,  can be found in this project: https://github.com/jirutka/ngx-oauth